# Problems to run session over database with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to run all session data over database via table.
But for some reason, it just ignore it when I try to set it up to run via database instead of "files".

Here is my configuration:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'sitecookie'; 
$config['sess_expiration'] = 2592000;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

And the table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `ci_sessions` (
 `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `data` blob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indeks for tabel `ci_sessions`
--
ALTER TABLE `ci_sessions`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 ADD KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`);
```

I've tried for hours to figured out where it goes wrong, but without luck.
Hope somebody have any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

I currently using this code it works fine and doesn't have a problem.
config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 7200;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

and this is the database table.

```
CREATE TABLE `ci_sessions` (
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data` blob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `ci_sessions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: It just ignore it here. Which CI version are you using?

Comment: define('CI_VERSION', '3.0.0');

Comment: I'm using 3.1.4.
So that shouldn't be the problem